# Does using setInterval but not actually doing anything cause memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, setinterval

I  have a script that checks whether or not some elements are on the screen and then if there are a certain number of elements are within those elements and if there aren't, it will 'redraw' them.  This is used for changing display options on search results where I can't use ajaxEVENT to do it.

Anyway, if the conditions aren't met, and nothing happens, does this cause any memory issues? I have the interval set to run every 1 second, and chances are nobody who's using this script will be on the same page for more than 5 minutes so..

Comment: You can use Chrome's developer tools to monitor memory usage.

Comment: Is there something making you suspect that it does leak memory?

Comment: @Pointy No, but I would just like to make sure that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It does cause memory issues because you're running the script all the time. Try binding some event handlers to whatever you can. The best way imo would be to create your own events and trigger them instead.

Comment: How exactly does an interval handler cause memory issues merely by running?  What evidence do you have?